# What plants would lizardfolk cultivate in this hostile world

Tags: science-based, medieval, survival, food

Lizardfolk are sentient and sapient humanoid reptilian creatures with heights between 190cm and 180 cm. Lizardfolk are partially mesothermic, with most of the waste heat, their muscles generate, being redirected to the brain. Regardless, they limit themselves to tropical climates, especially jungles and Florida.

There are three sub-species of lizardfolk, each with their corresponding tribe:

- **Nile-crocodile folk (Jaw tribe)**: Decent swimmers, but slower on land. They have very powerful jaws and could easily crush a human skull. They are the strongest and largest of the three. On top of that, they also have an osteoderm "armor" that protects even against weaker firearms.
- **Komodo-dragon folk (Attack tribe)**: Generalists with a potent poison that's also good for anyone who has a high blood pressure ;)
- **Asian-water-monitor folk (Coordinate tribe)**: The fastest and smartest (thanks to their lifestyle) of the three. They're awesome swimmers, excellent climbers and while not as powerful as the other two, they do pack a punch.

The three tribes live in peace, with their alliance being lead by the coordinate tribe.

Now, for some reason, there are these naruto-running titan zombies everywhere and want to kill anything sapient. The titan adjective refers to their ability to grow back entire limbs in minutes, not their size.

Lizardfolk just want to live a quiet and comfortable life, and while they have metabolic tricks up their sleeve, they still need food, especially the members of the coordinate tribe. Lizardfolk are omnivorous and more or less "garbage disposals". Though they're willing to eat gross things for survival, they do have dignity.

They'd rather avoid naruto-running titan zombies, not because those things are particularly strong, but because they love ganging up on people, which usually spells the end.

**So, they learned how to agriculture, now the question is what can they cultivate in that climate that gives the most nourishment while also being hardy enough to go on without much intervention from the lizardfolk?**

Tech-level is medieval, lizardfolk don't have access to any metals, though; so they use substitutes (when possible); the few iron items, they have, usually comes from shady dungeons and even shadier humans.

Comment: To my knowledge lizards are carnivores. How would agriculture help them? Are your lizards capable of processing veggies?

Comment: @cyber101 It's already in the question, paragraph 4 from the bottom.

Comment: Sorry can't read

Comment: The only flora my dragon would eat was red lettuce in the morning, other than that it was just insects. Since you are dealing with fictional creatures though I don’t see why you’d want to limit yourself to potato’s and figs, why not a fictional plant to.

Comment: brains don't actually need much heat, large brains have the opposite problem they produce a lot of heat just running that they need to get rid of.

Comment: do they know how to plant/have non poisonous type of plant/crops ? (i assume this was their first attempt in agriculture) especially root plant such as casava,potato,taro the wild/original one is poisonous until they do genetic mambo jumbo, theres a way/trick to remove the poison or make them edibel in some processing method but it quite a chore though.

Answer (score 6):

**Water hyacinth.**

[image: Water hyacinth]

http://www.iucngisd.org/gisd/species.php?sc=70

The [water hyacinth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontederia_crassipes) is an invasive weed in Florida.  Despite its ability to profligately take over aquatic ecosystems, it is edible and makes a fine animal feed.

https://www.allaboutfeed.net/Feed-Additives/Articles/2014/8/Use-of-water-hyacinth-in-fish-feed-1572246W/

Your people will grow water hyacinth.  Dried and pelleted water hyacinth will be fed to cockroaches, which will themselves be dried, pelleted, mixed 50/50 with more water hyacinth, and fed to farmed catfish.  Catfish are a fine food and those who wish variety
can have some water hyacinth salad with if they choose.

Also, most tadpoles are vegetarian.  The tadpole larvae of the "lizardfolk" will themselves do well with a diet of water hyacinth and the occasional baby roach, and can coexist with the catfish in the farm ponds.

Comment: Frogmen have long integrated into society and are now plaguing it with Pepe memes and whine about SJWs on /pol/. Lizardfolk live on their own and (wisely) don't bother with stuff like that.  They might seem similar, since they're mostly green and live in  water, but you shouldn't mix up the two.

Comment: A growing pond is also interesting with regard to zombies. Do zombies stop at the edge of the water or do they wade right in? If the zombies stop it's great as defense. If they wade in it could be a problem because the bottom of the pond could be just about covered in zombies since they probably can't get back out of the muddy-bottomed pond.

Answer (score 1):

### Tree crops, **livestock**, maybe root crops.

You may want look at the more "primitive" (i just don't like the term) forms of farming practiced by many tribal cultures. Which are often about **trees or root crops** instead of grains. Trees take care of themselves, fruit or nut trees, plantains and taro are popular. there are many tree crops favored by many cultures trees take care of themselves, all you have to do is clear the land and plant them. root crops can be similar but they require more frequent clearing, and it it only applies to root crops with many tubers for which harvest does not kill the plant, like manioc or groundnut. The trick with both is the plant itself persists after harvest for many year. This way the plants do not need constant work. These are really low effort crops. Zombies won't bother trees or root crops, at worst they are just fertilizer.

The better option is **pastoralism**, animals largely take care of themselves and are high in calories, some livestock problems but this due mostly to how much we have altered those animals, in their more primitive forms they will be easier to care for. Sheep, chickens, ducks, pigs, ect. Pigs in particular do very well in the tropics as do chickens. Basically you just need someone willing to sit an watch them and only act in the rare circumstance it is necessary. Even fish farming is possible but it is fairly labor intensive.